# GoogleAnalytics for own data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i am preparing mvc4 website in which i want to implement chart for specific "Area".
let me describe in detail,
there can be many "Area" in website say abc,xyz.
now in one area there can be number of users.

all i want is to maintain chart for particular "Area" like how many users visiting "Area",number of clicks per "Area",time users spent in one "Area" etc.

is this possible through GA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariable).  This allows you to create your own custom segments.

Comment: I get the solution,i just have to create cutomeVariable in Google Analytics account and use this in my application to track data which which want to, this line in GA sript do the trick for me    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'neighborhood', neighborhood.toString(), 1]);